# click on dynamically added DOM (ngx-bootstrap datepicker) element in angular

Tags: angular

I have used ngx-bootstrap datepicker in my project, under that i have submit button, What i want is, when I select date from datepicker, submit button should get active.

Submit

When I select date, button's disabled class should be removed.

Comment: Search in the library doc the right event for that control

Answer (score 0):

you can use form validation to disable the button

```
<form (ngSubmit)="CreateUser(f)" #f="ngForm">
<input [(ngModel)]='myDate' type="text" name="date" my-datepicker #date='ngModel' required >
<input type='button' value='sbmit' [disabled]='date.invalid'>
</form>
```

or if you want to do this by using class you can add

```
[ngClass]="{ 'YourInvalidClassName': date.invalid }"
```